# How to determine, whether an integer array has duplicate elements or not?

Tags: java

I was asked to write a code, which indicates, whether an integer array has duplicate elements or not. This is what I have so far:

```
int[] input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1};
boolean hasDuplicates = false;

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {
        if (input[i] != input[j]) {
            hasDuplicates = false;
        } else if (input[i] == input[j]) {
            hasDuplicates = true;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this code does not work as it was intended to be, because `hasDuplicates` is always `false`.

Comment: because you should return as soon as you determine the list has duplicates. you're essentially overwriting your previous results every iteration

Comment: If you trace the steps in your code manually, you'll see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have decided that the array `hasDuplicates`, you may never change that; you can't make disappear the duplicate after. Also use `break` the loop, at the moment `hasDuplicates` becomes true

```
int[] input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1};
boolean hasDuplicates = false;

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {
        if (input[i] == input[j]) {
            hasDuplicates = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (hasDuplicates)
        break;
}
```

---

Even easier in a method, directly use `return`

```
static boolean hasDup(int[] input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++)
            if (input[i] == input[j]) 
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also iterate over the array once if you use a HashSet. If the add() returns false then we know we have seen that number before.

```
int[] input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1};
boolean hasDuplicates = false;
HashSet<Integer> duplicateSet = new HashSet<>();

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if(!duplicateSet.add(Integer.valueOf(input[i])))
    {
        hasDuplicates = true;
        break;
    }
}

return hasDuplicates;
```

Comment: `new Integer()` can create unnecessary overhead. Use `Integer.valueOf()` instead, or, better still, autoboxing.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the benefit of **Set** data-structure as well:

```
int[] input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1};
boolean hasDuplicates = false;
    
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(input.length);

for (int i : input) {
   if (set.add(i)) {
       hasDuplicates = false;
   }
   else {
      hasDuplicates = true;
      break;
   }
}
```

**Set** **add(E e)** returns **true** if this set did not already contain the specified element.

In a short way:

```
int[] input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1};
boolean hasDuplicates = false;
        
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(input.length);

for (int i : input) {
      if (!set.add(i)) {
           hasDuplicates = true;
           break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8+ makes life easier. here you go

```
    int[] input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1};
    boolean hasDuplicates = false;
    if(Arrays.stream(input).distinct().count() != input.length)
        hasDuplicates=true;
    System.out.println(hasDuplicates);
```

Comment: This is nice and concise and readable. However, if the input has a million elements and the first two are duplicates, other answers will immediately return true. Yours will still look at the remaining 999,998 elements before returning true.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 Streams, stopping on the first found duplicate, a one-liner:

```
int[] input = {1, 2, 3, 4, 1};
boolean hasDuplicates = !(Arrays.stream(input).allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add))
```